# Newly-installed Ant doesn't run on Mac OS 10.12.5

Tags: java, macos, ant, macos-sierra

I just installed `apache-ant` using MacPorts:

```
sudo port install apache-ant
```

When I type `ant -version`, I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/tools/ant/launch/Launcher : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:482)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: My guess is there's a setup step (something like `ANT_HOME`??) that is missing, and that I'd have to notify the MacPorts devs about the bug.

Answer (score 0):

you need to upgrade the JRE you're running it with - the jar is compiled with 1.8

Comment: I'm running Java 8 update 144. That covers 1.8, right?

Comment: something is off.. if you read your error, it says `Unsupported major.minor version 52.0`  52 is java 8

Comment: Exactly my problem! Any ideas why that might be the case?